# What are some possible temp jobs in the US

Tags: job-search, job-change, careers, career-switch, healthcare-industry

My job is driving me nuts but I haven't been able to quit because I am unable to land another job.  I am trying to find alternative solutions besides just quitting and being unemployed as, well, not being able to land a job WHILE employed does not give me any confidence to land a job while unemployed.

I am trying to come up with a list of temp jobs that I can potentially do, WITHOUT prior experience, that can cover 1500-2000 or so in expenses (after tax) a month.  I am hoping to see if you guys have any ideas of jobs that meet the following requirements:

- Day time hours (I can't do night shifts - unless it ends before 2AM).
- Does not require prior experience.  Even jobs like bartending, waitressing, etc... I am sure the supply is greater than demand so preferential treatment will be given to people with good experience/references.
- I can be honest with the employer and say that this is a temp job or I don't plan to make a career out of it.  Basically I don't have to lie about anything.
- Also, since I have a master's degree and likely non-relevant job experience I need a job that doesn't care too much about you being "over qualified" or other non-sense (like amazing personal story) as long as you have the necessary skills.  The real story is I just need something to hold me over/survive.  (I don't want to come up with some BS like this is my dream job, I've always wanted to pivot to this career, or some sob/pity story, etc...)
- I am open to spending $1000-2000 and any amount of time to gain any certification needed - as long as the probability of landing a job afterwards is greater than 90%.  Also I'm willing to spend more, up to 10K if the prob of a job is even higher.
- I have prior coding experience in R and Python (not at the level of a developer) but at a level of a data scientist.

So far I've only been able to come up with the following:

- Uber driving (and other delivery based stuff) - this seems to be the most possible one, although it would increase my monthly expenses as I would have to get a car.  I also have a tough time pinpointing exactly how much one could make working 6-8 hours a day and a bit on the weekends.
- I've looked into stuff at hospitals (I have no issue being in the frontlines and dealing with Covid or any other job that puts mine in danger), but once again, I'm a bit jaded by education and certificates (I have BS, MA, some decent certifications and they have gotten me nowhere).  So while I'm willing to spend more money on "education", it has to pay off this time around.  In other words, I am totally open to hospital jobs - I just don't know if I can get one if I went and got a certification and don't have some amazing story about Mom passing away due to Covid and that hit me hard so I want to make sure no one else loses their mom.
- Something to do with coding since I can already code in Python/R a bit, so it wouldn't be too hard to go to one of those "camps" and learn how to develop.  But once again, it has to pay off.  I can't keep padding letters to my name and get nowhere.

Any suggestions would be great.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can't be looking very hard, there's 1000's of jobs that pay well and don't need experience. Cleaning, labouring, planting, spraying, pruning,... list is endless

Comment: So you can afford to throw up to 10k for certification? Not enough for an answer but.... how long could you live on that, and maybe then use this time to learn the skills you want?

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul Not being able to land a job while employed does not give me confidence to land a job while unemployed.  10k is like 3-4 months for me.  I could break my lease and downsize but that'll be 3k just to do it.  If I land a 1500-2000 a month job, 10k will last me 7-10 months.

Comment: @Kilisi I'll see what I can find.  I guess in all my life, experience has been such a big factor to everything that I figured most jobs need experience.  Even in HS when I worked as a sales associate at the mall unless you were friends with someone at the job, you needed prior experience.

Comment: @confused I think you are looking as "nice" jobs, those are highly competed for. Working warehouse, construction labor (depends on country) or factory floor can be as skill-free but also a lot less nice than working in airconed indoors, and subsequently are easier to get. Though I am not sure if you will be able to hit the 1500-2k mark, depends on location.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul 1500-2000k is like 24k a year.  If you worked minimum wage, 40 hr a week, before tax is 28k a year.  I don't know how "nice" of a job you are talking about.  I"m seeking 0 benefits beyond that.  Once again, I doubt if I walked into a construction site and asked for a job with 0 prior experience, they'd hire me.  I think uber may be the way to go, if I can cover the extra expenditures per month.  That'll free up the time to do additional job searching as well and network.

Comment: What kind of job do you do at the moment?

Comment: @confused that depends on country, can't really say about USA (which seems to be where you are) but in east/central Europe countries that is how you used to get construction jobs just few years ago. Carrying bricks or loading wheelbarrows doesn't require experience.

Comment: Being an Uber driver isn’t a career.  Let’s say the average ride is $30 and the average tip is 20% (and that’s actually on the high side).  You would have to calculate your share of the $30 yourself but I would estimate at least 100-200 rides a month to cover your current expenses.  You would need to cut your expenses significantly to live on the income off being an Uber driver.  This doesn’t even factor in the expenses of making sure your care is functional.  If your car ever breaks down then your income goes to 0, plus your expenses will increase, by several factors.

Comment: @Donald I have savings that I can tap into but I don't want to spend more than 1000-1500 a month in savings.

Answer (score 5):

Here are some things you might try:

- **Warehouse work.** Not a lot of skill required, and no learning curve. Depending on where you are, it might be abundantly available right now. Amazon is hiring an army.
- **Delivery work.** There is no particular skill required or a learning curve. It depends on where you live, but you may not need a car. In larger/warmer cities, you can do it with a bike.
- **Security Guard.** Lots of these are required right now to enforce mask requirements and such.
- **Freelance writing.** Not recommended if you need reliable or steady income, but it can compete with minimum wage jobs on average in annual income (emphasis on the "on average", as it is a cash management nightmare). Because you have the cash cushion, this could be for you.
- **Landscaping** Lots of landscaping work available right now as it is summer. It requires little more than knowing how to use a mower on the lower end and a trimmer more towards the middle.
- **General labor for renovations** I am doing quite well with lumber stock because so many people in North America are renovating. You could do things like painting.
- **Personal care aide** There is always a need for people who are willing to wipe elderly butts. Even during the depth of the Great Recession, these jobs were hard to recruit for.

You have to remember that the notion of retail, waitressing, and bartending being crappy miserable jobs you get stuck in is a very middle class/upper middle class notion. If you are working class, those jobs might be considered cushy as they are indoors and generally clean and that is one reason why they are so competitive and employers can demand experience.

Comment: Ok thanks for the perspective.  Didn't know AC was such a premium.

Comment: Retail saved my butt several times.  Good answer!